# Как правильно подключить script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу использовать на своем сайте данный код с code pen:

```
<style >
  .hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.btn-gallery img {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
</style>
<script src="js/gallery.js"></script>  
<a href="#gallery-1" class="btn-gallery">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1462774603919-1d8087e62cad?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=0ebd884b4d6ac379f42146a2b26fbf2e" alt="" />
    </a>
 <div id="gallery-1" class="hidden">
  <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1462774603919-1d8087e62cad?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=0ebd884b4d6ac379f42146a2b26fbf2e">Image 1</a>
  <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1460499593944-39e14f96a8c6?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=d8bc3d45d5eeaaf4f576665707f4fddb">Image 2</a>
  <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1434434319959-1f886517e1fe?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=218dfdd2c0735dbd6ca0f718064a748b">Image 3</a>
  <a href="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1431576901776-e539bd916ba2?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=a0941b28175909ca62f096eb533b0c97">Image 4</a>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/ksp9241/pen/OGadRE
Но я не могу правильно подключить js скрипт. Подключала его сверху, снизу не получается в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Вы подключили библиотеку Magnific Popup?
`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js` и `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В тэге head подключите jQuery, Ваш JavaScript и файлы Magnific Popup. Убедитесь, что jQuery подключен до Вашего JavaScript файла (как в коде ниже).

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
```